# Linq Order By With Different Method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity, sql-order-by

Looking way to Linq Order By;
Let me explain:

I have always 4 records.
Like

```
1. 233
2. 4232
3. 12
4. 21
```

And I would like to order them with specify the first element.
Example; 
first element is 12 then.

```
1. 12
2. 21
3. 233
4. 4232
```

another example;
first element 4232 then

```
1. 4232
2. 12
3. 21
4. 233
```

I hope I expalin clearly; how can I do it?

Current data provider code:

```
public static List<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> PlayersOnTheTable(int okeyTableID)
{
    using (var dbContext = new db_Oyun())
    {
        IQueryable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> okeyTablePlayer = dbContext.tbl_Okey_TablePlayer.Where(a => a.OkeyTableID == okeyTableID);
        IQueryable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> rows = okeyTablePlayer;
        return rows.ToList();
    }
}

 var playersOnTheTable = DataProvider.PlayersOnTheTable(okeyTableID)
                                     .OrderBy(x => x.OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber)
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Your OrderBy call looks correct. What is the issue?

Comment: Make two sequences, in the first order by equaling that element and the second take the rest - concat

Comment: Andrei, it just ordering by chair number; but I would like o order it by  UserID, so I can specify current user's position. Please could you check examples again thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum, I never used concat before. If possible please could you give a complete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution:**

```
var playersOnTheTable = DataProvider.PlayersOnTheTable(okeyTableID).OrderBy(x => x.OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber).ToList();

int yourSitPositionIndex = playersOnTheTable.FindIndex(x => x.UserID == userID);

var beforePlayers = playersOnTheTable.GetRange(0, yourSitPositionIndex);

IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> afterPlayers = playersOnTheTable.Except(beforePlayers);

IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> newPositions = afterPlayers.Concat(beforePlayers);
```

1. We'll get records by ordered;
2. Getting the index of our first element.
3. Getting all elements before our first element.
4. Filtering ordered record by before element. And getting the afterPlayers object with all others.
5. And concat to migrate 2 lists.

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes we want 4232 to be at the first element:

```
int[] ints = { 12, 233, 4232, 21 };
var firstInt = ints.Where(x => x == 4232); // This will be any number you want as the first value
var orderedInts = ints.OrderBy(x => x).Except(firstInt);
var customOrdered = firstInt.Concat(orderedInts);
```

Note this naively assumes the `Where` method always finds an element in the `ints` sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your example but something wrong in the custom ordered list; http://prntscr.com/4dz1fy

Comment: What is wrong? isn't this the desired behavior you asked for?

Comment: Result should be <4232, 21, 12, 233> but current is <4232, 12, 21, 233>, I think i couldnt exaplain sorry. I tried to give some example. But not enough. But now clear i think. Sorry.

Comment: Why does 21 need to come prior to 12? I thought what you wanted was to order the list except a specific value which you want to be first. In both your examples, the lists are ordered ascending.

Comment: Because I need to order players by chair numbers. http://prntscr.com/4dz42q  And declaring to current player's position to start point.

Comment: And how are you supposed to know which player sits in which chair?

Comment: By OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber; http://prntscr.com/4dz5jj  But important thing is current player on the session. So everytime player will watch and play the game in same view.